# QGIS generates multiple WMS requests in single image WMS mode

Tags: qgis, wms

I am testing my WMS service with QGIS and have noticed that even when the layer is configured in "non tile" mode (tile size is not specified) QGIS will generate multiple requests to my WMS service. This will only happen when the map area is large (QGIS running on large resolution monitor).

Is there a way for QGIS to only generate one request WMS service (with image pixel size request equal to exactly currently viewed map size)?

Comment: Many WMS services have a maximum image size they will support, so it makes sense to restrict the size of very large image requests.

Comment: Does the service have `<MaxWidth>` or `<MaxHeight>` set?

Comment: @IanTurton my WMS service does not have the values set for `<MaxWidth>` and `<MaxHeight>`

Comment: Not everyone sets that but if you can manage tiles why not play safe

Comment: @IanTurton It's not an option for my WMS service, it can only serve single image, so a non-tile mode only. I was hoping qgis has some setting I'm unaware of.

Comment: I don't understand the previous comment. Each GetMap is a separate and independent request. Tiled WMS GetMaps are just a bunch of single image requests in a row and any WMS server can handle them.

Comment: Have you tried to set very big tile size like 10000 by 10000 in the WMS connection settings?

Comment: Any WMS request is a single tile, there is no way for the server to tell if two requests come from the same or different clients

Comment: @user30184 the WMS service I wrote will not generate tiles that fit together, that is what I mean it can serve only a single image. The service is backed by an opengl application that generates the content dynamically. So more than one image request that covers the visible extent will result in a disjointed view to the user. So putting aside whether this is how WMS service should be written or not, I was just surprised that qgis would not let me force it to generate one request per visible extent, thats all.

Comment: @user30184 I will try setting a large tile size thanks!

Comment: Now it makes sense. Disjointed tiles is actually a common problem (see for example https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/concepts/metatiles.html). Let's hope that you will find a way to force QGIS to make bigger GetMap requests.

Comment: I can find where the max tile size option was added: https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/1576 and https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3768, but no mention that there would be any default value. The input mask seems to prevent giving bigger value than 9999.

Comment: @user30184, ok that does work, so I'll mark the question resolved. However it is still not ideal, setting width and height tile size to 9999 always requests image of that size from the server, even if the extent is nowhere near that size (which of course, causes performance issues). I guess that's understandable, that is what I am specifying for tile size. I guess I just wish there was a way to tell qgis, always request extent-sized image, up to the specified tile limit.

Comment: I recommend to write to qgis-users mailing list. If your obsesrvation is verified by other users create a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user30184 suggested increasing the tile size to a large number (larger than the pixel extent of the displayed map in qgis) solves this problem. This is not ideal as I do not know the end user's screen size. I can choose a size that I'm reasonably sure will be bigger than anything a user can throw at the service (like 10000x10000), but at that point this is such a large image to generate, that the experience is too slow.